# Sum $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[\frac1n\sin nx + \frac{1}{n^2}\cos nx\right]$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I want to find the following sum by using the complex methods for series ($z = \cos nx + i \sin nx$).
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[\frac1n\sin nx + \frac{1}{n^2}\cos nx\right]
$$
Here is my attempt:

$$
S_N =  \sum_{n = 1}^{N}\frac1n\sin nx + \sum_{n = 1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2}\cos nx
$$
I'm done with the first sum:
$$
 \sum_{n = 1}^{N}\frac1n\sin nx  = \Im  \sum_{n = 1}^{N}\frac{z^n}{n} \Rightarrow \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n = 1}^{N}\frac1n\sin nx = -\Im \ln(1 - z)
$$
But I'm stuck with the second one:
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2}\cos nx = \Re \sum_{n = 1}^{N}\frac{z^n}{n^2}
$$

Comment: complexification is not a word nor it means anything.

Comment: @jimjim If complexification doesn't mean anything then why is there a whole [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification) on it? There's quite a lot of content in that page, too.

Comment: @AidenChow : Can you explain how does link relates to this question? There is a lot of content on many other pages as well but that doesn't mean that they mean anything in the context of this question. Hope that clears up the meaning of not meaning anything, cause by your logic floccinaucinihilipilification  because there is a wikipedia page for it with a lot of content , look here : https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/floccinaucinihilipilification

Comment: @jimjim Well, how am I supposed to know what it means? I'm not the one who put the word in the question in the first place. I'm just saying that the word exists and maybe you should've asked the OP what he meant by it before editing it out.

Comment: @AidenChow : Let's assume what you are saying is correct, then according to you we should put that word back in this question, and then ask the OP to say what it means, but since you have the page with a lot of content on that word then you very well know that it has nothing to do with this question. So what is the next step? Maybe you are new on this site and have not seen enough posts to know at times people have no idea what they are saying so someone needs to clean it up for them, if you are right then edit the question, Also OP did not respond to complexification  meaning nothing.

Comment: @jimjim lol, yoy got called out because you did not know a word and then got defensive. Just chill. Complexification is a word, perhaps misplaced in thus case, but it is a word. You literally strawmen-Ed yourself. You said it is not a word and they try to tell us you meant to say it makes no sense in this context. Very different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we have 
$$\int_0^x \sin(nt)\,dt=\frac{1-\cos(nx)}{n}$$
Therefore we can write for $x\in [0,2\pi]$

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n \int_{0}^x \sin(nt)\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\int_0^x \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nt)}{n}\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\int_0^x \text{Im}\left(\log(1-e^{ix})\right)\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}6-\int_0^x \arctan(\cot(t/2))\,dt \\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\int_0^x \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac t2\right)\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac\pi 2 x +\frac{x^2}{4}
\end{align}$$

Comment: For arbitary $x$ this function isn't continuous if we extend it periodically, is it ?

Comment: It is not continuous at the end points only.

Answer (score 2):

Continue with

\begin{align}
 \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin nx }n
= -\Im \ln(1 - z)
= \frac i2 [\ln( 1-z) -\ln (1-\bar z)]
=\frac i2\ln(-z)= \frac{\pi-x}2
\end{align}

and use the result to evaluate

$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1- \cos nx }{n^2}=
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\int_0^x \frac{\sin nt  }{n}dt
= \int_0^x \frac{\pi-t}{2}dt= \frac{\pi}2x-\frac14x^2
$$

Thus
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left(\frac1n\sin nx + \frac{1}{n^2}\cos nx\right)
&= \frac{\pi-x}2 - \frac{\pi}2x+\frac14x^2
 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} \\
&=\frac{x^2}4 - \frac{(\pi+1)x-\pi}2 +\frac{\pi^2}6
\end{align}

Comment: +1. Maybe you can mention that the result holds for $x$ in a period and then extended periodically.

Comment: Your result is not correct for arbitrary values of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[15px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\bracks{{\sin\pars{nx} \over n} + {\cos\pars{nx} \over n^{2}}}}:\
{\large ?}}$

---

\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{nx} \over n} & =
\Im\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{\expo{\ic x}}^{n} \over n} =
-\,\Im\ln\pars{1 - \expo{\ic x}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,\Im\ln\pars{1 - \cos\pars{x} - \ic\sin\pars{x}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\arctan\pars{-\sin\pars{x} \over 1 - \cos\pars{x}} =
\arctan\pars{2\sin\pars{x/2}\cos\pars{x/2} \over 2\sin^{2}\pars{x/2}}
\\[5mm] & =
\arctan\pars{\cot\pars{x \over 2}} =
\arctan\pars{\tan\pars{{\pi \over 2} - {x \over 2}}} =
\bbx{{\pi \over 2} - {x \over 2}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{nx} \over n^{2}} & =
\Re\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{\expo{\ic x}}^{n} \over n^{2}} =
\Re\operatorname{Li}_{2}\pars{\exp\pars{2\pi\ic\,{x \over 2\pi}}}
\end{align}

where $\ds{\operatorname{Li}_{s}}$ is a
[Polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm)

With the [Jonqui$\grave{\mrm{e}}$re Inversion Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Relationship_to_other_functions)

\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{nx} \over n^{2}} & =
-\,{1 \over 2}\,{\pars{2\pi\ic}^{2} \over 2!}
\operatorname{B}_{2}\pars{x \over 2\pi}
\end{align}

where $\ds{\operatorname{B}_{s}}$ is a
[Bernoulli Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials). In particular,
$\ds{\operatorname{B}_{2}\pars{x} = x^{2} - x + 1/6}$.

Then,

\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{nx} \over n^{2}} & =
\pi^{2}
\bracks{\pars{x \over 2\pi}^{2} - {x \over 2\pi} + {1 \over 6}} =
\bbx{{1 \over 4}\,x^{2} - {\pi \over 2}\,x + {\pi^{2} \over 6}}
\label{2}\tag{2} 
\end{align}

---

Finally, with (\ref{1}) and (\ref{2}):
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\bracks{{\sin\pars{nx} \over n} + {\cos\pars{nx} \over n^{2}}} =
\bbox[15px,#ffd,border:1px solid navy]{{1 \over 4}\,x^{2} - {1 + \pi \over 2}\,x + {\pi \over 2} +
{\pi^{2} \over 6}}
$$

---